# What is the proper CiviCRM response when an Authorize.net CC transaction is declined?

Tags: civicontribute

using WP4.3.1 and Civi 4.6.9.  We got the below message from a member:
  "I renewed online with a credit card but did not get a confirmation of my
  payment. After completing and clicking on ‘make payment’ it took me back
  to the renewal page. If I am confirmed, could you please send me a
  receipt?"

When we checked on our end, it said Transaction Status: Declined (Card
 declined by issuer - Contact card issuer to determine reason.)

We are concerned that the system isn’t letting people know if there
was an issue processing their payment. I was pretty sure that it would
give them some sort of message, but wanted to check.

Answer (score 3):

Usually Civi displays an error message from Authorize, e.g., The card number is invalid.  Perhaps the user missed it?  [image]

I assume there are no odd CSS settings in your theme that might be hiding the message.